# How to check internet connection in .cmd (batch script) and run another command based on whether WiFi is connected or not?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wifi

Logic is as provided under

```
Setup WiFi Connection
if connection was successful:
     execute command1
else
     execute command2
```

WiFi Setup is done using the following command

```
netsh wlan connect ssid=%ssid% name=%name%
```

What I'm interested in is how to formulate my if condition.

Comment: I suppose you could always follow up the command with `NetSh WLAN Show Interfaces|Find /I "%ssid%">NUL&&(Echo=Executing Command 1)||Echo=Executing Command 2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
netsh wlan show interfaces | findstr "SSID.*%ssid%"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 GOTO connected
```